# Meaning of the phrase 表す通り

Tags: meaning, kanji, phrases

The context for this phrase is in a list of kanji spellings (kanji with hiragana), thus the definitions are not provided.

Breaking the phrase into its components:

`表す` - to reveal, show, display

`通り` - avenue, street, way

Taking the second part (way) in a non-literal sense leads me to conclude the phrase means roughly,

`the way shown` or more concisely `as shown`

Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/as+the+text+says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes 表す通り roughly means "as indicated", but it's not used on its own. It has to be preceded by some subject. For example:

> - 彼の外見が表す通り
>     as his appearance shows / as indicated by his appearance
> - 名前が表す通り
>     as the name suggests

Comment: Ah, thank you for the information.  I didn't know it wasn't usable on its own.